# Open SMS Send app with parameters in Android 2.2

Tags: android, sms

I have a problem.
Task: Open SMS Send(new message) standard program/window  with two parameters: phone number and text body.

I founded two solutions:

1)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS text");
intent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Works fine in all Android emulators 2.x .

**In real phone with Android 2.2 (possibly 2.3.x) I see only SMS body without phone number**

2)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:123456789");  
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);  
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "SMS text"); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Works fine in all Android emulators 2.x too.
**In real phone with Android 2.2 (possibly 2.3.x) I see only Phone Number without SMS body text**

In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Snippets tested on:
Samsung Galaxy Tap 7`  P1000 with Android 2.2
Motorola Milestone (U.S.A codename: Motorola Droid) Android 2.2 Up3

Both methods works well on Android 2.1 (LG GT540 Optimus).